# Firebase Invalid Resource Field Value when adding data to Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I want to add a data to my Firestore database from my NextJs project, but I've come across this error message:

> FirebaseError: Request failed with error: Invalid resource field value in the request.

Here is my code snippet, I've used the same example on the Firestore documentation

```
const db = getFirestore(initFirebaseApp())
return await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
  name: "Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
});
```

But I got this response

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.0.0_lite): RestConnection RPC 'Commit' 0x1d57740f failed with error:  {"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"} url:  https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects//databases/(default)/documents:commit request: {"writes":[{"update":{"name":"projects//databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA","fields":{"name":{"stringValue":"Los Angeles"},"state":{"stringValue":"CA"},"country":{"stringValue":"USA"}}}}]}

I assume it was because of the Firestore Rules but I've already changed it to

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}
```

I'm not using any auth as of now and fetching data seems fine, but I can't seem to add new data with `addDoc()` or `setDoc()`.
I'm currently using Firebase v10.0.0 if that helps

Comment: You mentioned that your able to fetch the data just fine but addDoc and setDoc doesnt work. Can you show how youre trying to add the doc via the addDoc method because setting the doc may run into issues if the fields have typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, I'm currently using Next.js and the problem only occurred on the client component.

So it turns out the Firebase config I store in the `.env` file, I've named them `FIREBASE_KEY` while this doesn't have any problem for server components, client component **can't access** them so basically my `initFirebaseApp()` returns an incomplete app.

The fix was just making the env variables have `NEXT_PUBLIC_` in front of them like `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY` and the function works fine now.